# what does "capturing the constraints" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've recently faced this sentence:

"Utility is a fixed or time-varying valuation that captures various QoS (quality of service) constrains"

I don't understand the meaning of the phrase "capturing the constraints". can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I found a powerpoint presentation (about cloud computing services) with a similar sentence which explains what those so-called "constraints" are. *In utility computing environments, users assign a “utility” value to their jobs, where utility is a fixed or time-varying valuation that captures various QoS constraints (**deadline, importance, satisfaction**).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This falls under tHe [third definition of “capture” in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capture) is

> to represent or describe something very accurately using words or images